# DevExpress>TcxDBTreeList Drag-Drop Tree Nodes (records)

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I want to move  tree nodes (db records) in TcxDBTreeList by dragging, is there a property on this component for this option ?

Comment: Ouch!  Good luck finding how anything works on a CX grid.  All the actual functionality is buried beneath layers upon layers of insane, impenetrable architecture.

Comment: the best place to ask this question is on the devexpress support site  http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**to enable drag-drop records on TcxDbTreeList**

write the codes below to events;

**onBeginDragNode** *event*

```
Allow:= True;
```

**onDragOver** *event*

```
Accept:=True;
```

set the cxDbTreeList's **DragMode** Property

```
DragMode:=dmAutomatic;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the OnBeginDragNode event. That looks to be the best place for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I actually had to move the nodes myself:

```
procedure TForm1.cxDBTreeList1MoveTo(...);
   var i:integer;
begin
   for i := 0 to Nodes.Count - 1 do
       begin
          // move the node in the tree
          TcxTreeListNode(Nodes[i]).MoveTo(AttachNode, AttachMode);
          // change the database to match
          UpdateParentForNode(NodeID, NewParentID, SortSpecifier);
   end;
   Done := True;
end;
```

It makes a certain amount of sense in the DBTreeView - the grid doesn't really have a good way to know exactly how you want to change the moved row(s). There's probably a sort order to be modified as well as the parent id.